# How to get query parameters in _app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

My environment: React.js + Next.js

I need query parameters in `app.jsx`.

When I wrote

```
console.log(1);
console.log(router); //(= useRouter import from next/router)
console.log(2);
console.log(Router); //(= Router import from next/router)
```

Chrome console prints queries well, but on terminal the query is empty.

```
1
ServerRouter {
  route: '/',
  pathname: '/',
  query: {},
  asPath: '/',
  basePath: '',
  events: undefined,
  isFallback: false,
  locale: undefined,
  isReady: false,
  locales: undefined,
  defaultLocale: undefined,
  domainLocales: undefined
}
2
{
  router: null,
  readyCallbacks: [],
  ready: [Function: ready],
  push: [Function (anonymous)],
  replace: [Function (anonymous)],
  reload: [Function (anonymous)],
  back: [Function (anonymous)],
  prefetch: [Function (anonymous)],
  beforePopState: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

Is there any way to get query in `app.jsx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use `useRouter` to get the query parameters. The query parameters are available only when you making a request to the Next.js server.

If you are using a Next.js server and you want to build the page based on the query params you can do that on the server side. But if you are using static files the query will always be empty on th first render due tu Next.js doing pre-render of a page.

Comment: Should I add 'getinitialProps' on app.jsx ?

Comment: "But if you are using static files the query will always be empty on th first render due tu Next.js doing pre-render of a page." 
Anything to solve this ? For example prevent the render of that page and redirect the req to another page (based on query params)

Answer (score 0):

You can access a `router` instance from the custom `_app`'s context object, which contains the query params both on the client and server.

```js
// pages/_app.jsx

const App = ({ Component, pageProps, router }) => {
  console.log(router.query); // Will log query params on client & server
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
};

export default App;
```